# Where can I buy a thin metal cable?

Tags: cables, buying

I need conect two small **printed circuit board**. I can use any metal cable (what is the correct name for it?) so I buy [this](http://www.eletroaquila.net/cabinho-estanhado-nu-30-0-05mm2-vermelho.html). It use the number "**NU 30**" but I don't find this number in other place and it is the thinner cable in this store.

The red cable "NU 30" is this

[image]

The size of plastic is 0.92mm or 0.036inch 
[image]

The size of the metal is 0.31mm or 0.012 inch:
[image]

This cable is not easy to break, so I can turn it 90 or 180 degree without problem, even being thinner. I say this because I an afraid to buy a so thinner cable that can easily break.

So my question is: Where can I find a cable that is thinner than this?

Comment: you'll have to be more specific about your requirements. [Magnet Wire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_wire) has very thin insulation, but without knowing what you need it for, it's hard to recommend any specific product.

Comment: Dealextreme has 0.1mm diameter wire with thin coating. But (as the 'put-on-hold' voters say in their canned message): if you state what you want to achieve we can give you a better answer, and your question can probably be released from hold.

Comment: Wouter van Ooijen, this can be a good cable. I try to find it there with no success. Can you give me the link?

Comment: I found that a good way to get a similar kind of thin wires is to strip out a spare or broken ethernet UTP cable. Those wires are pretty strong too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wire-wrap wire is 30AWG (about 0.25 mm). It is commonly used for this sort of thing and is available at many electronics suppliers.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge  Now this is easy understand this...

Comment: Lol.. Thanks for the reply. The correct name is Wire-Wrap wire!! And with 30AWG is easier to find it! Just google it.

Comment: @Rodrigo kynar wire is another name for it. Basically any small gauge wire. If it will move or flex a lot, make sure you get a stranded 30awg, not solid.